# How to pass values to react semantic ui form?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to Edit customer using same form I have used to add new customer. I am using react semantic ui form.

In Customer class, on Edit click it is calling onEditCustomer and fetching that customer details form DB. After that I am assigning fetched customer to "singleCustomer" and want to pass to AddCustomer form so I can Edit customer details there
but in render its giving me error on

```
customerForm =
<AddCustomer onAddFormSubmit={this.onAddFormSubmit} singleCustomer={this.state.singleCustomer}/>
```

The Error/warning is

```
> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might 
indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = 
{};` class property with the desired state in the AddCustomer component. 
in AddCustomer (at Customer.js:128)
in Customer (at App.js:10)
in App (at src/​index.js:7)


import React from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import AddCustomer from './AddCustomer';

export default class Customer extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        formClose:false,
        isAddCustomer:false,
        isEditCustomer:false,
        singleCustomer:[],
        users: []
    }
}

//fetch data 
componentDidMount() {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers';

    const myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Origin','https://localhost:44387');

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        myHeader
    };

    fetch(customerApi, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                users: result,
                isLoaded: true
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: false,
                error
            });
        }
    )


}
//New Customer record
onAddFormSubmit = data => {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers';

    const myHeader = new Headers({
        'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-type':'application/json'
    });

    fetch(customerApi,{
        method:'post',
        headers:myHeader,
        body:JSON.stringify(data)

    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                users:result
            })
        },(error) => {
            this.setState({ error });
        }
    )
}

//Edit customer record
onEditCustomer = custId => {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers/'+custId;

    const myHeader = new Headers({
        'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });

    fetch(customerApi,{
        method:'GET',
        headers:myHeader

    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                singleCustomer:result,
                isEditCustomer:true,
                isAddCustomer:true
            })
        },(error) => {
            this.setState({ error });
        }
    )

}

//Delete Customer

onDeletCustomer = customerId => {
    const{users} = this.state;
    this.setState({
        users: users.filter(customer => customer.customerId !== customerId)
    });
}

render() {
    const { users } = this.state;

    console.log("Edit customer");

    let customerForm;
    if (this.state.isEditCustomer || this.state.isAddCustomer){
        customerForm = <AddCustomer onAddFormSubmit={this.onAddFormSubmit} singleCustomer= 
  {this.state.singleCustomer}/>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {customerForm}
            <Table celled textAlign='center'>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body >
                    {
                        users.map(user => (
                            <Table.Row key={user.customerId}>

                                <Table.Cell>{user.customerId}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.name}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.address}</Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color='blue' onClick = 
          {()=>this.onEditCustomer(user.customerId)}>Edit</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color='red' onClick = 
         {()=>this.onDeletCustomer(user.customerId)}>Delete</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                            </Table.Row>
                        ))
                    }
                </Table.Body>

                <Table.Footer>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='5'>
                            No of Pages
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Footer>
            </Table>

        </div>
    )
}

}


In AddCustomer I want to set data to form but my form is not opeing.

import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class AddCustomer extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showCreateForm: false,
        id: '',
        name: '',
        address: '',
        formData: {}
    }
    if (props.customer) {
        console.log("Add customer constructor")
        this.setState({showCreateForm:true})
        this.state.formData = props.customer;
    }else{
        this.setState({showCreateForm:false})
    }
}

handleChangeName = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;

    console.log(value);

    this.setState({ formData: { name: value, address: this.state.formData.address } });

    //name: ""
    //address: ""
    console.log(this.state.formData);
}

handleChangeAddress = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({ formData: { name: this.state.formData.name, address: value } });

    //name: "ram" but now there is no address in formData
    console.log(this.state.formData);
}

handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
        formData: {
            name: this.state.name, address: this.state.address
        }
    });
    this.props.onAddFormSubmit(this.state.formData);
}

//On cancel button click close Create user form
closeCreateForm = () => {
    this.setState({ showCreateForm: false })
}

//Open Create new Customer form
openCreateCustomer = () => {
    this.setState({ showCreateForm: true })
}

render() {

    let formTitle;
    if (this.state.id) {
        formTitle = "Edit Customer";
    } else {
        formTitle = "New Customer";
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal closeOnTriggerMouseLeave={false} trigger={
                <Button color='blue' onClick={this.openCreateCustomer}>
                    {formTitle}
        </Button>
            } open={this.state.showCreateForm}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    Create customer
    </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Content>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                        <Form.Field>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder='Name' name="name"
                                value={this.state.name}
                                onChange={this.handleChangeName} />
                        </Form.Field>

                        <Form.Field>
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder='Address' name="address"
                                value={this.state.address}
                                onChange={this.handleChangeAddress} />
                        </Form.Field>

                        <br />
                        <Button type='submit' floated='right' color='green'>Create</Button>
                        <Button floated='right' onClick={this.closeCreateForm} 
       color='black'>Cancel</Button>
                        <br />
                    </Form>

                </Modal.Content>
            </Modal>

        </div>
    )
}

}
```